# Spinning particle lagrangians

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, supersymmetry, branes

What is the most general relativistic and non-relativistic lagrangian describing a spinning object in the following cases?

1. Classical point particles.
2. "Classical" point super-particles.

Comment: Hi riemannium: Note that resource recom., which are restricted on Phys.SE. can usually not be mixed with an actual physics q.

Comment: Petition for references deleted. I wish it helps to answer, ...Sometimes I am frightened to ask too broad questions,...

Answer (score 1):

The general action for a (super) p-brane is the [Green-Schwarz action functional](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Green-Schwarz+action+functional), which one should think of as the Nambu-Goto action extended to "supervolumes" and corrected by a certain WZW term that kills off additional degrees of freedom in order to make the case of $p=1$ equivalent to the usual superstring theory obtained by using the Polyakov action.